# Different return of safeAreaInset on iOS11 device without notch

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I am using the following snippet to get the safeAreaInset.top value to set up a constraint for my view.

```
extension UIDevice {
     var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
         if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
             if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter({ $0.isKeyWindow}).first {
                 return keyWindow.safeAreaInsets
             }
         }
         return UIEdgeInsets.zero
     }
}
```

On iPhone with iOS 12 or above, the safeAreaInsets seems doing fine, returning  `UIEdgeInsets(20, 0, 0, 0)` for device without notch and `UIEdgeInsets(47, 0, 34, 0)` for device with notch.

But on iOS 11, the safeAreaInset always return `UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)` for device without notch.

I tried it on different size devices without notch (iPhone7, iPhone8, iPhone8 Plus), and they only return `UIEdgeInset(0, 0, 0, 0)` on iOS 11 version (11.2, 11.4, etc), but returning the correct `UIEdgeInset(20, 0, 0, 0)` on other iOS 11+ version. (And on devices with notch, seems they return the correct safeAreaInset `UIEdgeInset(47, 0, 34, 0)` for all iOS 11 or above version.)

My question is, why safeAreaInset return differently only on iOS 11 device without notch, and what is the appropriate way to get the safeAreaInset.

Comment: Not related to your question but you should use `first(where: \.isKeyWindow)` and drop  the filter

Comment: The trouble is that iOS 11 was a long time ago. You can't even run an iOS 11 simulator in the current Xcode. Why not drop support for iOS 11 and stop worrying about it? No one's using it any more so who cares how it behaved?

Comment: @matt Yes we planned to drop support to iOS 11 in the near future. I am just curious if there a proper way to handle it (as I believe this issue is not a new issue) or if I wrote something wrong and messed things up.

Comment: Well you didn't tell us what you "wrote" so there's no way to know. But honestly, asking the _device_ about the safe area seems odd. It's a view feature and is meaningless without an interface. And a lot depends on _when_ you ask for the safe area.

Comment: @matt I set the safeAreaInset.top as a top constraint of a subview, but found that it behaves differently ONLY on iOS 11 devices without a notch. Anyway, it seems not much we can do when the device/os returns an undesired result. Currently, I just add an extra if case for iOS11...

Comment: Well, I remember iOS 11, and devices without a notch behaved just fine. My device had no notch and there was nothing wrong with its safe area.

Answer (score 0):

**Declare window in your AppDelegate first like this:**

```
var window: UIWindow?
```

**You can get the safeAreaInsets like this:**

```
let _appDelegator = { return UIApplication.shared.delegate! as! AppDelegate }()

var _safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
    get {
        if let window = _appDelegator.window{
            return window.safeAreaInsets
        }else if let vc = _appDelegator.window?.rootViewController{
            return vc.view.safeAreaInsets
        }
        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly to say this answer didn't work. The main problem is not about fail to refer to the AppDelegate.window, but about the keyWindow returning different safeAreaInset. For device with notch (e.g. iPhone X), it return the same safeAreaInset for all devices on iOS 11 or above, but for device without notch (e.g. iPhone 8), it return different safeAreaInset only on iOS 11.